# How do I set a default checked item on a List Item in a ListView with Android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a Checked ListView with a few items in it. Here's just a quick example of how I'm creating it:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends ListActivity {

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      List<String> settingsitems = new ArrayList<String>();
      settingsitems.add("Item A");
      settingsitems.add("Item B");

      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, settingsitems));

...
```

How do I set a default item to be checked when the list is loaded? For example, when the list is shown I'd like `Item B` to be checked only.

I've tried adding the following before and after `setListAdapter` and it doesn't work:

```
this.getListView().setItemChecked(1, true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the [docs for the setItemChecked() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked%28int,%20boolean%29) state:

> The is only valid if the choice mode has been set to CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE or CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE.

the default choice mode for the ListView is CHOICE_MODE_NONE which means that if you do not explicitly set it to either SINGLE or MULTIPLE your call to setItemChecked() will not do anything.

so try adding this line before you call setItemChecked():

```
this.getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Comment: Looks like it's working now after you gave me this code. My setItemChecked needed to be moved after setListAdapter.